# MVVM in Universal Windows Platform problem binding

Tags: mvvm, uwp, binding

Ok so I am Using Visual studio and uwp. I created a WeatheVM, to bind to my page, as a Resource. Evrerytime I create the Resource, it say that "Cannot create WeatheVM" I am very frustrated, I don't understand why is not letting me, I need this to access my properties.

```
<Page x:Class="uwpMVVM.View.MainWindow"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="using:uwpMVVM.View"
      xmlns:vm="using:uwpMVVM.ViewModel"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <vm:WeatherVM x:Key="vm" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="box"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="40"
                        QueryIcon="Find"
                        />
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="53*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="247*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

by the way my VM is a public class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you gave, I saw that you created an instance of `WeathVM` in `Page.Resources`, but did not reference it.

You can set the Grid's DataContext to vm so that you can import the resources you created.

```xml
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
    <!-- Other code -->
</Grid>
```

Suppose you have a `Temp` property to display. After setting the DataContext, you can bind it like this.

```xml
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
    <TextBlock Text={Binding Temp} />
</Grid>
```

This is a [complete MVVM example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnshews_blog/2015/09/09/a-minimal-mvvm-uwp-app/), you can modify it with reference to it.

Best regards.

Comment: I know, But I cannot do that if visual studio keeps telling me "Cannot create WeatheVM" Since I have several clases, it wound make sense to create it as a resource key, then I can do something like:bind the data context of the grid to Weather.currentObservations

Comment: I put the DataContext as you told me, and the same error

Comment: Hi, Can you provide the WeatherVM code and the Code-behind of your current page, which will help with problem analysis?